# ElasticSearch 5.6 is there a way to modify ES search response?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Let's say I have a search response like

```
        "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "customer",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "5",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "name": "TEST1",
                "surname": "Soanems1"
            }
        },
```

I want to be able to modify the data before the user gets the response. Let's say the "name" field has a value of "TEST1" and I want the data at rest to stay "TEST1" but I want the user to see a different value, for example, "TEST12345". Is there a way to do it?

**Is there a way to create a custom plugin that does this transformation for me? (there are some not trivial transformations that I want to do to the response)**

Comment: that's a funny requirement. Is the transformation the same for each user or do you have different rules depending on which user is requesting the data.

Comment: different depending on user